# Unable to change encoding to UTF-8 in Open Office

Tags: encoding, utf-8, openoffice

I see the following when I look at a document in Finnish

[alt text http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/oo-bug-finnish.png](http://files.getdropbox.com/u/175564/oo-bug-finnish.png)

The problem seems to be in encoding. *I am not sure which encohing OO uses by default.*

I can see the documents in  terminal without the encoding problems.
I wrote the documents in Vim where the documents are readable.

**How can you change OO's encoding to UTF-8?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue may not be an encoding problem, but a font issue, the font may not have the characters you need. Try changing the documents font to something basic, like Times New Roman and see if your characters reappear.

Comment: Thank you for the hint! --- The problem was not in the font but in the encoding. --- UTF-8 was not enough. The correct encoding is Western European.